# Return statement not returning value for email

Tags: python, error-handling, beautifulsoup, return

I'm trying write something that will return email body text once ran. What I have so far is:

```
from exchangelib import Credentials, Account
import urllib3
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

credentials = Credentials('fake@email', 'password')
account = Account('fake@email', credentials=credentials, autodiscover=True)

for item in account.inbox.all().order_by('-datetime_received')[:1]:
    html = item.unique_body
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")
    for span in soup.find_all('font'):
        return span.text
```

My issue is with the last line reading `return span.text`. If I were to replace this line with `print(span.text)`, it runs perfectly and prints the body text of the email. However when replaced with `return`, it throws an error reading `SyntaxError: 'return' outside function`. I've been digging into the issue, and I can't seem to figure out why it is throwing this issue. I'm new to Python and could use some help. What can I do to solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As your error would indicate, you need to place your `return` **inside a function**

```
from exchangelib import Credentials, Account
import urllib3
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

credentials = Credentials('fake@email', 'password')
account = Account('fake@email', credentials=credentials, autodiscover=True)

def get_email(span): # a function that can return values
    return span.text

for item in account.inbox.all().order_by('-datetime_received')[:1]:
    html = item.unique_body
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")
    for span in soup.find_all('font'):
        email_result = get_email(span) # call function and save returned value in a variable
```

Answer (score 1):

the reserved word `return` can only be used inside of a function like:

```
def hello(name):
    return "hello " + name
```

if you're not going to work inside a function (which you're not right now) try doing something like:

```
emails = []
for item in account.inbox.all().order_by('-datetime_received')[:1]:
    html = item.unique_body
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")
    for span in soup.find_all('font'):
        emails.append(span.text)
```

Whats happening is you will now add the `span.text` object to the list called `emails`. Then you can use the list for later use.